# Insert into array during foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fairly certain the answer is no, but is it possible to insert something into an array during a `foreach` loop? Ideally at the very spot you are at in the array during the loop.

For example:

```
foreach($stock->StockData as &$stock) {    
        if($dateTime < $stock['DateTime']) {
            // INSERT NEW RECORD AT THIS SPOT IN THE ARRAY
        }   
}
```

As I say, I'm fairly certain the answer is no, but rather than build a new array, I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Beware of the `&$stock`: if the reference is not needed it would be safer to remove it. PHP doesn't have block scope which means after the loop $stock is still pointing to the last item of your initial array. So if later you assign something to $stock you will be effectively modifying your array. You can prevent this by unsetting $stock after the loop if you really need the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stand corrected!

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch05_07.htm

It apparently is just fine to do this in PHP.

According to the reference, PHP operates on a copy of the array when you start a foreach iterator, meaning that the iterator will not be corrupted by operations on the original array within the body of the foreach!

Comment: Sounds correct, I often unset things while iterating over an array and never ran into trouble for it, so I guess inserting is fine too.

Comment: And then just using `array_splice` to insert the changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You **really** don't want to mutate an object is being iterated on. It will break your iterator/loop and could possibly crash the script/program by accessing or changing memory that you don't have access to anymore, possibly because array size has reduced.

Comment: @djfm please see:
    Note:
    When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.
    As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: This is generally true, but note the reference in the answer I've submitted.  PHP apparently iterates over a copy of the array, not the array itself.  This means that you are not mutating the iterated object.

Comment: Sure, but regardless of iterating on a copy or original, if you have ten items in an array and while iterating through it, you delete two in the mid. Now the array is 8 items long whereas your loop is going through ten items. At indices 8 and 9, you try to mutate the item and php goes boom! :D

Comment: I think you missed the point.  The iterator operates on a copy.  You are not mutating the copy, you are mutating the original.  This means that you cannot corrupt your iterator.